# Changing Force of my fall after a jump

Tags: unity

I'm trying to change the  speed of the jump. I noticed if I jump twice the fall speed force gets implemented. Otherwise it is unchanged. If I try to change my onGround to be else false it remains false. Any Ideas.?

```
public class PMRigidBody : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private ConstantForce cf;
    public float fallSpeed = -10;
    private bool onGround = false;
    private int jumpHeight = 7;

    void Start (){
        // get the components
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        cf = GetComponent<ConstantForce>();
    }       

    void Update()
    {
        float dist = 1f;
        Vector3 dir = new  Vector3(0, -1, 0);

        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, dir * dist, Color.green);

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, dir, dist))
        {
            onGround = true;
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    onGround = false;
        //}

        if (onGround)
        {
            cf.force = Vector3.zero;
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {

                onGround = false;
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0);
                rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.up * Time.deltaTime * 10);

                cf.force = new Vector3(0, fallSpeed, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's walk through two loops of your code, starting with a player on the ground pressing jump. I'm also going to assume you're running around 60 fps.

**Frame 1 Update**

- We raycast down 1 unit and find the ground. `onGround = true`
- `onGround = true` so we set `cf.Force = 0`
- The "Jump" button was pressed this frame, so:

  - `onGround = false`
  - we set our vertical velocity to 7
  - we move up by `Time.deltaTime * 10` or about 0.166
  - we set `cf.force` to `fallspeed`

**Frame 2 Physics Step**

- Our vertical velocity moves us up roughly `Time.fixedDeltaTime * 7` or about 0.14 (neglecting gravity and downward force for the moment, but they'll only reinforce the effect we're about to see...)

We're now about 0.3 units higher than we started.

**Frame 2 Update**

- We raycast down 1 unit **and still find the ground** because we're only 0.3 units away from it! `onGround = true`
- `onGround = true` so we set `cf.force = 0`
- "Jump" is not pressed this frame, so we don't try to set `cf.force` back to `fallspeed`.

So: what's happening is your onGround test is too inclusive. It's counting you as still being on the ground the frame after you jump, and resetting your force to zero as a consequence. I'd recommend tightening the onGround check, or disabling it while you have an upward velocity (since I can't very well land on the ground if I'm moving away from it).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using public variables that show up in the inspector.

**Any variables written in the inspector override your code.** Check the inspector variables first, if they're changed and your code is changed, I'm not sure how to help you. Good luck! :)